# Время (сек) в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Как убавлять значение переменной, каждую секунду?
Я попробовал создать Корутину, и вызвать ее в Update. Так неправильно вроде, т.к всё время вызывается данная Корутина.
 Например:

```
int speed = 100;

if(speed > 0) speed-=5;
```

Вот эти 5 надо минусовать каждую секунду

Comment: [таймеры] (https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) использовать не пробовали?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Корутину стартовать в апдейт - плохо, т.к. вы каждый кадр будете новую корутину создавать. Можно запустить в `Start`.

Или в `Update`:

```
private const float CheckPeriod = 1f;
private float m_LastCheck = CheckPeriod;
private int m_Speed = 100;

private void Update() {
    m_LastCheck -= Time.deltaTime;
    if (m_LastCheck < 0) {
        m_Speed -= 5;
        m_LastCheck = CheckPeriod;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. есть функция FixedUpdate(),которая выполняется не каждый кадр,а 1 раз в секунду например,интервал выполнения функции можно проставить в настройках проекта

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TimeManager.html

https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/class-TimeManager.html

2. таймер

   ```
    float timeLeft = 30.0f;

    void Update()
    {
        timeLeft -= Time.deltaTime;
        if(timeLeft < 0)
        {
            GameOver();
        }
    }
   ```

Comment: Простите, с чего Вы взяли, что FixedUpdate вызывается раз в секунду? Это не так.

Comment: Хоть и можно поставить вызов FixedUpdate() раз в секунду - это полнейший бред и выдумывание велосипеда.

Comment: я и написал например и дал как вариант

Comment: Я и написал, что это очень плохой пример, и в целом плохая практика использовать колбек обновления физического движка для отсчета времени. С таким же успехом можно ограничить фпс до 1 и в Update() отсчитывать время.

Answer (score 0):

Один из вариантов вызова определенного метода каждые n секунд:

```
InvokeRepeating("LaunchProjectile", 2.0f, 0.3f);
```

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.InvokeRepeating.html
https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.InvokeRepeating.html

Comment: `InvokeRepeating` использует рефлексию. Не рекомендовал бы использовать. Плюс, сложно отследить изменения, если переименовали метод.